# pear DB Error: extension not found sql server in windows 7 apache server

Tags: php, sql, sql-server-2008-r2, database-connection, pear

pear DB Error: extension not found sql server in windows 7 apache server

hi all, i face some problem during i connect sql server with pear DB.

following is pear i already had.

1. Archive_Tar        1.3.10  stable
2. Console_Getopt     1.3.1   stable
3. DB                 1.7.14  stable
4. HTTP_Request       1.4.4   stable
5. MDB2               2.5.0b3 beta
6. MDB2_Driver_mysql  1.5.0b3 beta
7. MDB2_Driver_mysqli 1.5.0b3 beta
8. MDB2_Driver_sqlsrv 1.5.0b3 beta
9. Net_Socket         1.0.10  stable
10. Net_URL            1.0.15  stable
11. PEAR               1.9.4   stable
12. SOAP               0.12.0  beta
13. Structures_Graph   1.0.4   stable
14. XML_Util           1.2.1   stable

and in php i already inclue extension
**php_sqlsrv_53_ts_vc9.dll**

in php.ini i already include the dll

**extension=php_sqlsrv_53_ts_vc9.dll**
i download the dll in http://download.microsoft.com/download/C/D/B/CDB0A3BB-600E-42ED-8D5E-E4630C905371/SQLSRV20.EXE

following is php code tp connect db.

```
<?php
/**
 * PEAR
 */

require_once 'DB.php';
$DB = new DB();
$DBIn = $DB->connect($CONF['db'], true);

?>
```

i get the error DB **Error: extension not found**

Answer (score 1):

Use `phpinfo();` to make sure the extension is really loaded. You might have forgotten to restart the web server software after changing `php.ini`.

Answer (score 0):

I know its a long time since the question/answer... But still.
I was also facing this issue, **DB Error: extension not found**, and it happened to me on a new Centos 8 with PHP 7.x. and an old, legacy PHP application, where PEAR packages were user. Eventually, what I found out, were missing PHP modules, mysqli and mysqldn. So first, check the modules installed, running:

```
php -m
```

And than, if mysql stuff is missing:

```
apt-get install php-mysqlnd
```

or

```
yum install php-mysqlnd
```

Also a reminder...In my case I was also missing php-json and php-mbstring, so be sure to repeat the steps above for all missing modules.

Also, after installation, restart your apache/httpd:

```
service apache2 restart
```

or

```
systemctl restart httpd
```

BR